# How to auto count Current Employees for department in CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, ssms

The employee has a default department that company workers will associate with, also the system will track which department the worker is currently working in.

How to count CurrentEmployeesCount?

```
CREATE TABLE Departments
(
    DepartmentID          INT PRIMARY KEY,
    DepartmentName        NVARCHAR(100),
    CurrentEmployeesCount INT --???
);

CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    EmployeeID  INT PRIMARY KEY,
    DepartmentID INT DEFAULT '???',

    FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentID) 
        REFERENCES Departments (DepartmentID)
);
```

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM Employees WHERE DepartmentID = ....` ?

Comment: You could maintain the value using a trigger or a computed column using an inline function, but a *view* would probably be a better solution.

Comment: I must wonder about the frequency with which you need to know the number of employees per department. This sounds like both premature optimization and an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).